# Finding Duplicate entries in a file using command prompt

Tags: cmd, findstr

If you have a large file and there are many lines containing duplicate information, but it isn't a perfect duplicate, i.e.

SSID 1: WiFi1

SSID 2: WiFi1

SSID 3: WiFi1

SSID 40: WiFi1

So for this I tell it to start at the end of the string ,more filename.txt| 'findstr /E', but is there a way to tell it to only print out the first instance of a string, say similar to the unix 'uniq -U'?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a native Windows batch file to give you the first line of a search match.

```
type "filename.txt" | findrepl "WiFi1" /o:0
```

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` (by aacini) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.